# Flask - run code with parameter from API Endpoint

Tags: python, flask

I am trying to create endpoint which define some variables and allow server to run code with this variables. When I visit for ex. "http://localhost/dodaj/1/Tom/Andy" I see print which is in second and third row, but I cant use this URL parameters (gniazdo, a, b) to run another python code which them as variable. Code is starting but how to put this three variable to it?

```
@app.route('/dodaj/<gniazdo>/<a>/<b>')
def user_view(gniazdo=None, a=None, b=None):
return 'Dodano ' + gniazdo + ', od ' + a + ' oraz ' + b 
def run_script():
     file = open('action.py').read()
     return exec(file) app.run(port=5000)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass them as arguments to the function you created.

```
def run_script(gniazdo, a, b):
    print(gniazdo)
    print(a)
    print(b)
    file = open('action.py').read()
    return exec(file) app.run(port=5000)

@app.route('/dodaj/<gniazdo>/<a>/<b>')
def user_view(gniazdo=None, a=None, b=None):
    run_script(gniazdo, a, b)
    return 'Dodano ' + gniazdo + ', od ' + a + ' oraz ' + b
```